# LiveData update on object field change

Tags: android, observable, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I'm using Android MVVM architecture with LiveData. I have an object like this

```
public class User {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

And my view model looks like this

```
public class InfoViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
    MutableLiveData<User> user = new MutableLiveData<>();

    public InfoViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
        User user = new User();
        user.setFirstName("Alireza");
        user.setLastName("Ahmadi");

        this.user.setValue(user);
    }

    public LiveData<User> getUser(){
        return user;
    }

    public void change(){
        user.getValue().setFirstName(user.getValue().getFirstName() + " A ");
    }
}
```

How can I make sure when some field in user object changes observers get notified? BTW it is important to me to keep this data in the separate object and not use primary values like Strings in my ViewModel.

Comment: I wander whta's the difference of the first answer with the second one to this post, the second one looks more easy.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

I don't think there is any best practice as such recommended by android for this. I would suggest you to use the approach which uses cleaner & less boilerplate code.

If you are using android data binding along with `LiveData` you can go with the following approach:

Your POJO object would look something like this

```
public class User extends BaseObservable {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    @Bindable
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.firstName);
    }

    @Bindable
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.lastName);
    }
}
```

So you would be already having a class which notifies whenever its property changes. So you can just make use of this property change callback in your MutableLiveData to notify its observer. You can create a custom MutableLiveData for this

```
public class CustomMutableLiveData<T extends BaseObservable>
        extends MutableLiveData<T> {


    @Override
    public void setValue(T value) {
        super.setValue(value);

        //listen to property changes
        value.addOnPropertyChangedCallback(callback);
    }

    Observable.OnPropertyChangedCallback callback = new Observable.OnPropertyChangedCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPropertyChanged(Observable sender, int propertyId) {

            //Trigger LiveData observer on change of any property in object
            setValue(getValue());

        }
    };


}
```

Then all you need to do is use this CustomMutableLiveData instead of MutableLiveData in your View Model

```
public class InfoViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    CustomMutableLiveData<User> user = new CustomMutableLiveData<>();
-----
-----
```

So by doing this you can notify both view & LiveData observer with little change to existing code. Hope it helps

Comment: I do not know that why . in my class could not find BR.

Comment: @Sup.Ia Re-build the project to generate BR file

Comment: is there a way to do this without data binding? I mean, an approach like this one in where you can choose when the liveData's value has changed.

Comment: I was reading this article https://medium.com/@tylerwalker/property-aware-mutablelivedata-with-kotlin-4fb5830ae730 that explains same solution but in Kotlin. However I couldn't get it to work. I think it is outdated because it is using lifecycle version = 1.1.1. How to set the value inside of `onPropertyChanged()` in Kotlin? `value = value` does not compile.

Comment: BR stands for? Anyone knows that?

Comment: The BR is also giving me issues

Comment: BR stands for BindingResources. It is created when compiling your project. For every `<variable>`-tag in your data-bound layout xml there will be a reference in BR. Similar to normal resources that are also defined in xml (e.g. R.string.something)

Comment: Hi, it works without the CustomMutableLiveData class. Why do i need the class?

Comment: Who unregisters the listener if we change to a completely different value object? And don't we register a new listener object every time we change one of the User object fields?

Comment: i think @morpheus05 is right.

Answer (score 28):

When using MVVM and LiveData, you can re-bind the object to the layout so it will trigger all changes on the UI.

Given "user" is a `MutableLiveData<User>` in the ViewModel

**ViewModel**

```
class SampleViewModel : ViewModel() {
    val user = MutableLiveData<User>()

    fun onChange() {
        user.value.firstname = "New name"
        user.value = user.value // force postValue to notify Observers
        // can also use user.postValue()
    }
}
```

**Activity/Fragment file:**

```
viewModel = ViewModelProviders
            .of(this)
            .get(SampleViewModel::class.java)

// when viewModel.user changes, this observer get notified and re-bind
// the user model with the layout.
viewModel.user.observe(this, Observer {
    binding.user = it //<- re-binding user
})
```

**Your layout file shouldn't change:**

```
<data>
    <variable
        name="user"
        type="com.project.model.User" />
</data>

...

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/firstname"
        android:text="@{user.firstname}"
        />
```

Comment: This is working! but does re-binding has any performance drawbacks ?

Comment: It's simpler and more clear approch than marked as best.

Comment: This just seems wrong to me. Isn't the whole point of using LiveData to not rebind?

Comment: Instead of binding user, you can bind viewModel, then you won't need to re-bind.

Comment: binding viewModel   does not work . for me re-binding the object works very well.

Comment: This is not rebinding, it just refreshes the variable, which will reflect the change on the UI. Don't see a problem here.

Comment: It is probably better to create new user instead of using existing one

Answer (score 28):

If you are using Kotlin and LiveData, I can offer you 2 ways - with and without extension fucntion:

### Without extension function

```
liveData.value = liveData.value?.also { it ->
    // Modify your object here. Data will be auto-updated
    it.name = "Ed Khalturin"
    it.happyNumber = 42
}
```

### Same, but with extension

```
// Extension. CopyPaste it anywhere in your project
fun <T> MutableLiveData<T>.mutation(actions: (MutableLiveData<T>) -> Unit) {
    actions(this)
    this.value = this.value
}

// Usage
liveData.mutation {
    it.value?.name = "Ed Khalturin"
    it.value?.innerClass?.city= "Moscow" // it works with inner class too
}
```

Comment: Great idea. I would enhance it further by using `actions: MutableLivedata<T>.() -> Unit`, to that the lambda could be written without `it`

Comment: Elegant. The point I missed was that setting the exact same value object triggers the notification to observers. Hopefully it won't be 'optimized' in future releases.

Comment: how it suppose to work? This will be fired only once (during the initialization), not every time the value changes

Comment: how does it behave on additions to an .innerArray ?

Comment: This no longer works.

Answer (score 5):

> How can I make sure when some filed in user object changes observers
> get notified? BTW it is important to me to keep this data in the
> separate object and not use primary values like Strings in my
> ViewModel.

You can use androidx.lifecyle.Transformation class to monitor for individual fields.

```
val user = MutableLiveData<User>();
//to monitor for User.Name
val firstName: LiveData<String>  = Transformations.map(user) {it.firstName}
val lastName: LiveData<String>  = Transformations.map(user) {it.lastName}
```

you update user as per normal, and listen for firstname/lastname to monitor for changes in those fields.

Comment: Are you sure this works? in theory Transformations are only updated when the observer for root object changes, so it will still need to change liveData value and not field

Answer (score 5):

From [reddit - @cedrickc's answer](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/bvn1rk/how_to_correctly_update_field_of_class_in_livedata/) :

add an extension function to MutableLiveData:

```
fun <T> MutableLiveData<T>.modifyValue(transform: T.() -> T) {
   this.value = this.value?.run(transform)
}
```

Comment: fun <T> MutableLiveData<T>.setField(transform: T.() -> Unit) {
    this.value = this.value?.apply(transform)
}

Answer (score 0):

For your observer get notified you should use `setValue` if you do this
`user.getValue().setFirstName(user.getValue().getFirstName() + " A ");` your observer will not be notified !

View Model

```
public MutableLiveData<User> getUser() {
    return user;
}
```

Activity / Fragment

```
mModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(InfoViewModel.class);
mModel.getUser().observe(this, s -> {
    // User has been modified
});
```

Somewhere in your activity / fragment

This will trigger the observer :

```
mModel.getUser().setValue(user);
```

If you want to update only one field from an object instead of update the whole object you should have multiples `MutableLiveData<String>`

```
// View Model
private MutableLiveData<String>         firstName;
private MutableLiveData<String>         lastName;

//Somewhere in your code
mModel.getFirstName().setValue(user.getValue().getFirstName() + " A ");
mModel.getFirstName().observe(this, s -> {
    // Firstname has been modified
});
```

Answer (score -2):

**Simple Easy Solution in 2021 (also works for `StateFlow`):**

The key point here is, `.value` must be changed to a **Different Object (reference)**, so that the binding ui will get updated.

```
//Your model
data class Student(val name: String)

//Your ViewModel class
fun onStudentClick() {
    val newName = "Kate"    //change field/property

    _student.value = _student.value.copy(name = newName)    //must be different object!!
}
```