# Wrapping MutableList in either LiveData or MutableLiveData

Tags: kotlin, android-livedata, mutablelivedata, mutablelist

What is the recommended means of wrapping a `MutableList` within either `LiveData` or `MutableLiveData` such that one can modify the list and observe the changes it undergoes ?

I have some fairly short tables (<20 items) in Room (It caches the values retrieved from a server). I would like to retain a mutable subset of these items; to be used as filters in queries for other, larger, tables. My thinking was to assign a `MutableList` to the model class in my application and make it observable by wrapping this class in either `MutableLiveData` or `LiveData`. Then by updating the items in these selections I could trigger the necessary queries on the large tables.

Presently my code has the following structure, I've stripped it down in my question to what I thought was relevant. Eventually I would like to use multiple `keyset` in more complex queries. My simplified model file is as follows,

```
class Model(application : Application) : AndroidViewModel(application)
{
  val keys    : LiveData<List<Key>>
  val keyset  : LiveData<MutableList<Key>>
  val values  : LiveData<List<Value>>
  init {
    keys   = repository.keys
    values = repository.values
    keyset = mutableListOf<Key>() // I'm not entirely sure how to instantiate LiveData<MutableList<Key>>
  }
}
```

it relies upon the repository,

```
class Repository(private val queryset : QuerySet)
{
   val keys   : LiveData<List<Key>>   = queryset.getKeys()
   val values : LiveData<List<Value>> = queryset.getValues()
}
```

Which relies upon the queryset

```
@Dao
class QuerySet(application : Application) : AndroidViewModel(application)
{
  @Query("SELECT * FROM KeyEntity")
  fun getKeys() : LiveData<list<Key>>
  @Query("SELECT * FROM ValueEntity WHERE key in (:keys)")
  fun getValues(keys : MutableList<Key>) : LiveData<list<Value>>
}
```

The `Key` and `Value` classes are simply the POJO for `KeyEntity` and `ValueEntity` and simply specify the same fields.

Should I be using `MutableLiveData` or `LiveData` for this purpose ? If so how should one implement `keyset` ? Perhaps there is a more canonical manner for doing so ?

Answer (score 5):

### LiveData vs. MutableLiveData

I was not sure whether I had to wrap my `MutableList` as `LiveData<MutablList<POJO>>` or as `MutableLiveData<MutableList<POJO>>`, where `POJO` is an instance of either a database entity or a data class proxying one or more database entities. [Sneh Pandaya](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46814399/958580) succinctly explains the difference between the two classes. I was also unsure as to how to instantiate them. The following creates the instance but the `value` of `keyset` is initialized as `null` and one must set an initial value for the `MutableLiveData`.

```
class Model(application : Application) : AndroidViewModel(application)
{ ...
  val keyset  : LiveData<MutableList<Key>>
  init { ...
    keyset = MutableLiveData<MutableList<Key>>() // Initialized as null
    keyset.value = mutableListOf<Key>()          // Assign an empty list
  ... }
... }
```

There is a nuance in `MutableLiveData`, it does not formally encapsulate the data. That is when it wraps an item it does not expose the wrapped items methods as it's own emitting notifications as the wrapped item is modified. It merely tracks when the wrapped item has been swapped out (See  [Gznlt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52075248/958580)). [Samnang CHEA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50545043/958580) provides a nice method for supporting this.

### Location, Location, Location, ...

I was unsure of where to formally place the `keyset` attribute. The [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata#observe_livedata_objects) provides the following information; as it turns out I was on the correct path.

> #### Update LiveData objects
>
> LiveData has no publicly available methods to update the stored data.
>     The MutableLiveData class exposes the setValue(T) and postValue(T) methods publicly and you must use these if you need to edit the value stored in a LiveData object.
>     Usually MutableLiveData is used in the ViewModel and then the ViewModel only exposes immutable LiveData objects to the observers.

### Queries

What I have not worked out yet is how to trigger an update of the `values`.

Comment: Any luck? I am facing the same problem now.

Answer (score 3):

**The Observer is notified only on Changes to the Value of LiveData**

**This is true for both LiveData and StateFlow**

When you declare instance of `MutableLiveData<MutableList<Any>>`, and then you add value to the list wrapped inside MutableLiveData as `variable.value.add(Any)`, the observer would not be notified. It does not listen to such changes where the internal content of the list/model is updated.

There are different workarounds to make the observer notified by creating Extensions but that's quite complication to achieve the simplest task.

The simplest way is as follows:

```
private val _mobileTopUp = MutableLiveData<List<DataModel>>(emptyList())
```

Then create a simple Mutable List where you will collect the items. You can declare this list on top of your function so it gets empty everytime you make function call to avoid redundant data or not. That totally depends on you

```
val list = mutableListOf<DataModel>()
list.add(it)
_mobileTopUp.value = list
```

Now, the **observer will be notified** because we are setting list as value of LiveData here.

Comment: I have an edit to update `_mobileTopUp`  to be a MutableLiveData instead of MutableList. It didn't make sense to set `_mobileTopUp.value` on it otherwise.

Comment: @Soulis yes, you are correct. it was a type. let me update that.