# Using MutableLiveData with complex Objects and Collections

Tags: java, android, observable, android-livedata

After I have read the Android documentation and various other articles about LiveData,
I came to know that the main benefit of it is its state-awareness.

The concept may be very nice for simple Objects like a String,
but I am wondering why it is suggested to use it for complex types or collections.

As a list can easily be modified without triggering any notification (as the list is just a reference inside the LiveData-Object),
I think it is very error-prone and required one to do additional steps.

For example:

```
...
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
MutableLiveData<String> mld = new MutableLiveData<>();
mld.setValue(list);

...
// probably some other Class/Method...
List<String> sameList = mld.getValue();
// won't trigger any notification but changes the initial list
sameList.add("Some String");

// needed to trigger notification:
mld.setValue(sameList);
```

Wouldn't it be much better to have an Interface (or at least two) like with implementing the Observer-Pattern to be able to notify the observing objects whenever any changing action is triggered? Just with the additional state-awareness?

This won't help with the list-example in the first place unless there isn't some list-type implementing the interface, but if one writes a model-class that basically offers special instructions on a list, this would make way more sense in my opinion.
The model itself could have well-designed logics and enforce notifications for every modification.

The calling class does not need to care about when a notification is triggered as long as it applied itself as an observer.

So is LiveData basically designed to be used with predefined classes from other libraries so that one does not need to modify existing code but can just use LiveData as a wrapper and decide when to update manually?

Or is it more common to just extend the LiveData class and add the functionality there?

With Kotlin it seems to be possible to write just an extension-function, like mentioned here:
[Refreshing MutableLiveData of list of items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49246237/refreshing-mutablelivedata-of-list-of-items)

But that would mean that one has to write a wrapper-function for every function present in already existing models. This may be feasible with aspect-oriented programming.

Comment: The mutability of the list is not an issue of LiveData itself. If you want to prevent this, use `Collections.unmodifiableList` to make the mutation of the list be an error, and save that into the LiveData.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce: That won't change the problem much and would even make it worse as long as one still needs to modify the data somewhere. Objects with methods like addItem(...) would still require manual triggering of the notification. There is no coupling between any modifying method and a notification.

Comment: Well, try not to mutate in place and you'll be fine

Comment: @EpicPandaForce: You mean to put the methods for mutating the object into the ViewModel?

Comment: I mean you should prefer to use `Collections.unmodifiableList` once a list is set up, and otherwise when you want to make an edit, do `new ArrayList<>(currentList)` and edit that and set it to the LiveData.

Comment: That would only prevent the modification of lists but not of other complex objects. Preventing modification is not the goal here. It is more about defining which modification will trigger a notification. Sticking to the list example it might be changing the state of a list member. Setting the whole list again sounds like waisting memory and would not tie business-logics to notifications like when using the Observer-pattern.