# Update Object type LiveData with Databinding

Tags: android, mvvm, data-binding, android-livedata

I want to update views via databinding with livedata. Lets have a look at the scenario.

**Data Class**

```
data class Movie(var name: String = "", var createdAt: String = "")
```

**ViewModel**

```
class MyViewModel: ViewModel(){
   var pageTitle: MutableLiveData<String>()
   var movie: MutableLiveData<Movie>()

   fun changeTitleAndMovieName()
       pageTitle.value = "Title Changed"
       movie.value.name = "Movie Name Changed"
   } 
}
```

**XML**

```
<layout>
    ...
    <TextView
        ...
        android:text="@{`Title: `+viewmodel.pageTitle `Name: `+viewmodel.movie.name}"/>

    <Button
        ...
        android:onClick="@{() -> viewmodel.changeTitleAndMovieName()}"/>

</layout>
```

**What I want to do?**

- When the button is pressed, the title and the name of movie should change and reflect to the view.

**What is happening now?**

- Only page title is changing because of String type LiveData.
- Movie name is NOT being reflected in the view because of Movie type LiveData and I am changing the property of Movie type LiveData's property.

Is there any way to update Movie type LiveData to the view when any property is changed of the Movie.

I dont want to re-assign the object to the livedata e.g. `viewmodel.movie.value = Movie(...)`

Comment: show the code how you are observing viewmodel changes

Comment: "I dont want to re-assign the object to the livedata" <- this is the only way to update livedata. If `MutableLiveData.setValue()` is not called, then observers will not be notified.

Comment: @SanlokLee see my answer below. Btw Thanks for your appreciated comment on my question.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the answer of my question. A hint from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48020377/livedata-update-on-object-field-change#answer-48194074)

The reference link's answer is a bit long change todo. I have got a very simple solution.

**Here's what I did:**

Just inherit you Data Class with **BaseObservable** and just call the method notifyChange() after your Object's property change from anywhere.

**i.e.**
**Data Class**

```
  data class Movie(var name: String = "", var createdAt: String = "") : BaseObservable()
```

**ViewModel**

```
class MyViewModel: ViewModel(){
   var pageTitle: MutableLiveData<String>()
   var movie: MutableLiveData<Movie>()

   fun changeTitleAndMovieName()
       pageTitle.value = "Title Changed"
       movie.value.name = "Movie Name Changed"

       //here is the megic
       movie.value.notifyChange()
   } 
}
```

Comment: if it works for you that's great. However there are reasons why people wouldn't recommend this. Your view is not observing the `MutableLiveData`, but it is just observing the `BaseObservable` inside the `MutableLiveData`. Whatever observing `MutableLiveData<Movie>` is still not notified. Your solution is essentially same as without having `LiveData` at all, just put `var movie: Movie` in `ViewModel` and it will still work.

Comment: Also, wrapping an observable with another observable is an anti-pattern. As I already mentioned in above comment, sometimes inner observable fires notifications, while outer observable does not, and vice versa.

Comment: So how do you suggest the best way to update/notify views on changing of Object's property while using LiveData. **P.S. Do not re-assign the object.** @SanlokLee

Comment: I would recommend re-assigning the object. In fact having a mutable data object in observer pattern is generally not recommended. I suggest changing every attribute in `Movie` to use `val` instead of `var`.

Comment: If you must use mutable object, then I suggest just exposing the movie name with `movieName: MutableLiveData<String>()` and then manually update your `movie` and `movieName` object.