# ViewModel observers not reacting to LiveData<POJO / Bean> changes

Tags: android, mvvm, viewmodel, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

it is happening to me that when I have a **LiveData< String >** (or any primitive type) and I change its value by doing `liveDataObject.setValue("exampleValue)`
the observer in my fragment is notified and it does works correctly.

But, when instead of a primitive type, the LiveData is made by a POJO or a Bean, like **LiveData< Player>**:

```
public class Player { private int number; private String name, private Team team //getters and setters}
```

then, in order to update its attributes, for each correspondent event I'd like to call something like `getPlayer().getValue().setPlayerName("Jordan");`

*getPlayer()* returning the LiveData< Player > instance, *getValue()* the Player inside the LiveData object...
**The problem is that this is not notifying the observers about a change**, because it only notifies when I use the :

`liveDataObject.setValue(new Player(...))`

what I think is not appropiate to call every time an attribute of the player changes...
Do you know the correct way to do this?

Thank you

Comment: check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48020377/livedata-update-on-object-field-change

Comment: thank you, I hope is the correct solution.