# Invoke MutableLiveData Observer without using postValue()

Tags: android, android-livedata, mutablelivedata

Suppose, I've a `MutableLiveData<User>`. So if I update a variable in User let say `userName` using the value like

```
var user = MutableLiveData<User>()
user.postValue(User())
user.value.userName = "ABC"
```

it won't call the observer. So I have to call a postValue to invoke it.
Is there any to invoke observer after updating one property of `MutableLiveData` object.

Comment: Livedata working based on the object you specified, here it is User and based on the attributes of user object

Comment: please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48020377/livedata-update-on-object-field-change

Comment: here you update the property of MutableLiveData not the User. You could do something like `user.postValue(User().apply{userName = "ABC"})`, or instantiate User( )before, modify the property and then post it

Answer (score 0):

At the end @Stachu solution works but, I have made a change by passing the value of apply block in the `postValue()` like this -

```
user.postValue(user.value.apply{ userName = "abc" }.value)
```