# LiveData<Any> can not observe changes made in object by other code

Tags: android, android-livedata, android-mvvm

I have a domain object, let's say `User`:

```
class User(var id: String, var name: String) {

   init {
       EventBus.getDefault().register(this)
   }

   @Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
    fun onNewName(event: NewNameEvent) {
        this.name = event.newName
    }
}
```

This class is notified by global [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus). From the other side, there is a ViewModel (of activity) which has:

```
val user = MutableLiveData<User>(Application.my.user)
```

Issue is that viewModel's `user` doesn't react on any changed made by event bus in `Application.my.user`.  What do I miss?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that LiveData is listening for changes of the `User` object and not its fields. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48194074/15106139) is a solution to a problem similar to yours.